# Any Data Explorer query for number of close/open cycles?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Any way to see a question's history of being closed and opened?

Comment: I don't think they're duplicate questions.  Greg seems to know much more about the data dump and is asking for specific things to be added.  My question is whether it's possible or not, with an apparent answer of "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are our of luck here,

We age out older than 3 days close votes. So there is no history kept in the data dump.

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/5876/close-vote-stats

Perhaps, you should change this to a feature request for the data dump to add close and open counts to a Post.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the PostHistory table is [exposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer) in the Data Dump, yes!

I created a query to find the number of times a question has been closed and reopened:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/761/community-controversy

Comment: If you're modifying this query, be careful about running it -- it is very heavy because there isn't an index on PostHistory.PostId. The original query took 2 attempts to get results (timed out the first try). I will see if I can get an index on that column for next month's update.